# Oracle 11g R2 eats swap a lot

Tags: centos, oracle-11g

We have an oracle 11.2.0.1 server with 8 cores and 12gb ram. It's CentOS 5.6 and it has 12gb swap file. Oracle's memory target is 4gb and memory management is automatic. It has MegaSAS Raid controller with 4 drives.

Database itself is around 15gb with lots of blob data.

During sql selects server hangs a lot with high waiting for io, around 100%. It hangs in a way that I can't even connect to it using ssh. It eats around 5-6 gigs of swap. selects doesn't include blob data only plain rows.

I have `vm.swappiness = 0` and I even tried `swapoff` but it still hangs.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Is that a 64-bit CentOS 5.6?

Comment: @Janne yes it's 64-bit Centos 5.6 with all latest updates installed

Comment: Did you configure shared memory settings and/or hugepages as Oracle suggests you to do?

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/pre_install.htm

Comment: @Janne actually i didn't installed oracle on this server, someone else did it. But i think shared memory is configured correctly